# How do I change the image of a PictureBox when a CheckBox is checked?

Tags: c#, checkbox, picturebox

I am busy making a simple game in Visual C#, and I have no idea how to do this. Is there a way to set a PictureBox's image when a CheckBox is checked? What is the actual code for setting the image?

Thanks,

Varmitharen

Comment: I have to go. I'll elaborate tomorow.

Answer (score 2):

It depends how you've got your image, but you can use:

```
this.pictureBox.Load(imageFileName);
```

or

```
this.pictureBox.Image = image;
```

where `image` is of type `Image`

Just to complete the answer:

```
this.checkbox.CheckedChanged += new EventHandler(Checkbox_CheckedChanged);

private void Checkbox_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Change image here
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a CheckedChanged event of a CheckBox that you can subscribe to with a handler that changes the image. Link: [CheckBox.CheckedChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.checkbox.checkedchanged.aspx)

Comment: Yes, I know how to get the event working. Sorry if my question was ambiguous. What I meant was: Whats the actual code to change the pictureBox?

Comment: You should be able to use the PictureBox.Image property and set it to a new Bitmap or whatever.

Answer (score 0):

```
this.MyCheckbox.CheckedChanged += new EventHandler(MyCheckbox_CheckedChanged);

private void MyCheckbox_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.MyPictureBox.Image = // Your image here
}
```